# CPU maxed out by garbage collection

Tags: .net, web-applications, garbage-collection, cpu, azure-web-app-service

I have a Web App running on Azure, two P3V2 instances running. Every now and again one of the instances will hit 90%+ CPU usage and stop responding to further requests until it's restarted - If left it will keep itself in a hung state indefinitely. Taking CLR profiles and memory dumps reveals that it appears to be garbage collection treads using all of the CPU. The problem is, I'm not sure where to go next to solve this. None of the stack traces show any of our code so we don't know what's triggering the GC to go nuts in the first place. Any pointers?

[image]

Comment: Try to start with the PerfView's analysis - like [in my article](http://tooslowexception.com/scenario-mystery-of-the-very-long-gc-pauses-in-net-windows-service/)

Comment: Is it possible to run PerfView in an Azure web app?